# Python: Print count of all terms in alphabetical order, even if zero

Tags: python

I'm running a loop through 360+ txt files that counts occurrence of certain words in each file. Code is below:

```
>>> cnt=Counter()
>>> def process(filename):
words=re.findall('\w+',open(filename).read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in words_fra:
        cnt[word]+=1
    if word in words_1:
        cnt[word]+=1
print cnt
    cnt.clear()

>>> for filename in os.listdir("C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\Project"):
process(filename)
```

I have two lists, words_fra and words_1, with about 10-15 words in each. This puts out the matching word with the count, but it does not print words with zero count and it lists words in order of frequency.

Example of output:

```
Counter({'prices': 140, 'inflation': 107, 'labor': 46, 'price': 34, 'wage': 27,     'productivity': 26, 'capital': 21, 'workers': 20, 'wages': 19, 'employment': 18, 'investment': 14, 'unemployment': 13, 'construction': 13, 'production': 11, 'inflationary': 10, 'housing': 8, 'credit': 8, 'job': 7, 'industry': 7, 'jobs': 6, 'worker': 4, 'tax': 2, 'income': 2, 'aggregates': 1, 'payments': 1})
Counter({'inflation': 193, 'prices': 118, 'price': 97, 'labor': 58, 'unemployment': 42, 'wage': 32, 'productivity': 32, 'construction': 22, 'employment': 18, 'wages': 17, 'industry': 17, 'investment': 16, 'income': 16, 'housing': 15, 'production': 13, 'job': 13, 'inflationary': 12, 'workers': 9, 'aggregates': 9, 'capital': 5, 'jobs': 5, 'tax': 4, 'credit': 3, 'worker': 2})
```

I'm okay with the formatting, except I need all of the word counts to be displayed, even if its zero, and I need the word counts returned in alphabetic order not by frequency.

What can I tack on to my code to accomplish that? It would also be preferable to I could get it into a nice csv format, with the words as column headers and counts as row values.

Thanks!

EDIT: The top is what the current outputs look like. The bottom is what I want them to look like.

```
Wordlist="a b c d"
Counter({'c': 4, 'a': 3, 'b':1})
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 0})
```

Comment: um... 'all the word counts'?  does that mean words that appear in at least one of the found files (but not in the file you're looking at?

Comment: Sorry, I need each counter output (one per file) to list each word, in order, with its count, even if zero.

Answer (score 0):

To print all the words in your word list, you can loop over the words in the word-list before you start looking for words in the files, and add them to the result dictionary with 0 as a count.

To print them in the right order use use the [sorted()](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) built-in.

Something like this:

```
import re

wordlist = words_fra + words_1
cnt = {}
for word in wordlist:
    cnt[word] = 0

words=re.findall('\w+',open('foo.html').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wordlist:
        cnt[word]+=1

for result in sorted(cnt.items()):
    print("{0} appeared {1} times".format(*result))
```

If you want to sort so the most common words come first, you do this:

```
for result in sorted(cnt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]):
     print("{0} appeared {1} times".format(*result))
```

Comment: To add the 0 valued words in, you could do something like `Counter.fromkeys(all_words,0) + result_counter`

Comment: Yeah using Counter here is a good idea, but as this clearly is a beginners question, doing it without stdlib help may also be a good idea. :-)

Comment: I am using Counter, my apologies for not mentioning. Does that change how I sort the results? For now, I just Print cnt

Comment: @CoS: It doesn't change how you sort it, but apparently Counter can't count to zero. I'd recommend you to in this case drop Counter, because it's not really helping.

Answer (score 0):

if you want result in `Counter` then you have to override `__add__` method of `Counter` to accept `0`. For example ..

```
In [8]: from collections import  Counter

In [9]: Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2,'white':0})+Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2,'white':0})
Out[9]: Counter({'red': 8, 'blue': 4})

In [10]: 
    ...: class Counter(Counter):
    ...:     def __add__(self, other):
    ...:         if not isinstance(other, Counter):
    ...:             return NotImplemented
    ...:         result = Counter()
    ...:         for elem, count in self.items():
    ...:             newcount = count + other[elem]
    ...:             result[elem] = newcount
    ...:         for elem, count in other.items():
    ...:             if elem not in self:
    ...:                 result[elem] = count
    ...:         return result
    ...:     

In [11]: Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2,'white':0})+Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2,'white':0})
Out[11]: Counter({'red': 8, 'blue': 4, 'white': 0}) #<-- now you see that `0` has been added to the resultant Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in sorted(words_fra + words_1):
    print word, cnt[word]
```

Comment: I should put this in the code in place of print cnt, correct?